# make std::optional constructor emit implicit conversion warnings

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, implicit-conversion, clang++

I'm trying to rid my codebase of lossy implicit conversions, so I'm compiling with the `-Wconversion` flag under clang++.  The following code is expected to output a warning, but does not.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <optional>


int main() {
  size_t x = std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max();
  std::cout << x << std::endl;

  auto x2 = std::make_optional<uint8_t>(x);
  std::cout << (int)*x2 << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

On the `make_optional` line, my `size_t` is silently narrowed to a `uint8_t`.  If instead I write `uint8_t x2 = x;` for example, I get the expected narrowing conversion warning.

This also happens when I use the `std::optional` constructor.  In the code I gave, [make_optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/make_optional) overload 2 is called which calls [optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional) constructor overload 6.  This constructs the optional as if direct-initializing the contained value, and direct initialization does not raise an implicit narrowing conversion warning.

Other than writing an `optional` class of my own that does not hide narrowing conversions, is there any way to cause the above code to raise a narrowing conversion warning?

Comment: I was about to say "use clang-tidy", but apparently there is no check covering that. Even in build from today's master, 9.0.0svn. Maybe other static-analyzer can detect such case.

Comment: `make_optional` is sensed to use deduction... else directly use `optional<T>`.

Comment: Maybe file it against libstdc++, I am not exactly sure why that doesn't generate a warning, as making a similar constructor myself did. Interestingly I also got a warning in all cases with  MSVC (C4244 or C4267 for size_t).

Comment: No compiler to hand, but doesn’t `optional<uint8_t>{x}` fail as desired?

Answer (score 1):

[List initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) prohibits narrowing conversions.

By the way, it looks like some compilers do warn on the issue: https://godbolt.org/z/P8Mv8v83d